# Kill and restart multiple processes that fit a certain pattern

Tags: unix, shell, scripting, kill

I am trying write a shell script that will kill all processes that are running that match a certain pattern, then restart them. I can display the processes with:

```
ps -ef|grep ws_sched_600.sh|grep -v grep|sort -k 10
```

Which gives a list of the relevent processes:

```
user 2220258       1   0 16:53:12      -  0:01 /bin/ksh /../../../../../ws_sched_600.sh EDW02_env
user 5562418       1   0 16:54:55      -  0:01 /bin/ksh /../../../../../ws_sched_600.sh EDW03_env
user 2916598       1   0 16:55:00      -  0:01 /bin/ksh /../../../../../ws_sched_600.sh EDW04_env
```

But I am not too sure about how to pass the process ids to kill?

Comment: `killall` would work on Linux, but not on all Unixes. On Solaris, for example, `killall` kills *all* active processes.

Comment: Well, all _killable_ processes by the user. Which is indeed great fun when running it as root...

Comment: The killing part is easy, the "then restart them" part is considerably harder which leads me to believe the whole operation could be handled much more smartly from the beginning.

Answer (score 6):

The `sort` doesn't seem necessary. You can use `awk` to print the second column and `xargs` to convert the output into command-line arguments to `kill`.

```
ps -ef | grep ws_sched_600.sh | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill
```

Alternatively you could use `pkill` or `killall` which kill based on process name:

```
pkill -f ws_sched_600.sh
```

Comment: Why the sort? You're going to kill them anyways.

Comment: no need grep and xargs as well.  ps -ef | awk '/ws_sched_600/{cmd="kill -9 "$2;system(cmd)}

Answer (score 1):

```
pkill ws_sched_600.sh
```

If you are concerned about running your command on multiple platforms where pkill might not be available

```
ps -ef | awk '/ws_sched_600/{cmd="kill -9 "$2;system(cmd)}
```

Comment: `pkill` doesn't exist on Mac OS at least (it's `killall` here).

Comment: I think this should work. Have not used AWK much but need to start!

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for

```
for proc in $(ps -ef|grep ws_sched_600.sh|sort -k 10)
do
    kill -9 proc
done
```

edit:

Of course... use xargs, it's better.